# Existence of almost complex structure on smooth even dimensional manifold

Tags: differential-topology, smooth-manifolds, almost-complex

I am trying to prove that if $M$ is an even dimensional manifold, and the bundle of linear frames of $TM$ admits a reduction of its structure to group to $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, then $M$ admit's an almost complex structure.

In theory I feel like this should be easy, however I am struggling on the details. I know that if the frame bundle admits a reduction of its structure group to $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ then we have that $TM$ admits a covering of vector bundle charts $(U,\phi)_i$ such that the transition functions take values in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$. Let $\tilde{I}$ be a complex structure on $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$, and then $GL_n(\mathbb{C})\subset GL_{2n}(\mathbb{R})$ is the subgroup of linear transformations which commute $\tilde{I}$. I thus want to define $I$ in each bundle chart by:
\begin{align*}
I_U=\phi^{-1}\circ(\text{Id}_U\times \tilde{I})\circ \phi
\end{align*}
Checking that this is independent of bundle chart then seems too easy as if $(V,\psi)$ is another bundle chart such that $U\cap V\neq \emptyset$ then:
\begin{align*}
    (\psi^{-1}\circ \phi)\circ I_U\circ (\phi^{-1}\circ \psi)=I_V
\end{align*}
trivially, so a partition of unity argument implies that this defines a global $(1,1)$ tensor field on $M$. It is also easy to see that in any chart $I_U\circ I_U=-\text{Id}$. However, I have never used the fact the transition functions take values in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$, so I suspect I am missing something. Do I need to check that $I_V\circ I_U=-\text{Id}$ as well for some reason?

Comment: Aren't you using the $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$ transition functions in the second equation?

Comment: @Kajelad I am, but if you defined them using different bundle charts these still glue together to form a $(1,1)$ tensor field. I think I figured it out though, you need to check that $I_V\circ I_U=-\text{Id}$ as well, because a partition of unity is going to include a sum like $f_VI_v+f_U I_U$, so when finding $I^2$ you pick up terms like $I_V\circ I_U$. Proving that that satisfies $-\text{Id}$ makes explicit use of the fact that the transition functions take value in $GL_n(\mathbb{C})$.

Comment: You don't even need a POU, strictly speaking. You can simply define $I$ by $I|_U=\phi\circ I_U\circ\phi^{-1}$. and the result will be well-defined and smooth.

Comment: @Kajelad Ok, so then why do we need to check that on the overlap $I_U\circ I_V=-\text{Id}$? which I'm convinced we have to do because other wise we could define an almost complex structure on any vector bundle

Comment: I seem to have misread your notation;, $I_U$ is a local form on the bundle itself, not on the trivialization. The second equation should just be that $I_U=I_V$ on their common domain.

Comment: @Kajelad Ok, does my argument make sense?